# Mostrar ou esconder uma div conforme opção selecionada

Tags: javascript, html

Estou trabalhando com um sistema de cadastro, onde todos os funcionários serão cadastrados, mas nem todos terão acesso ao programa. Para isso, estou utilizando um *select* com o nível de acesso que ele vai ter.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="nivel_acesso" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Nível de Acesso</label>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
        <select class="form-control" id="nivel_acesso" required onchange="option_check()">
            <option value="">Selecione</option>
            <option value="0">Sem Acesso</option>
            <option value="1">Administração</option>
            <option value="2">Informática</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group" id="hidden_div" style="display:none;">
    <label for="usuario" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Usuário</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="usuario" placeholder="Usuário" required>
    </div>
</div>
```

Por exemplo, se quero cadastrar um funcionário que terá acesso a parte de administração, ele precisará de um usuário para fazer login. Estou mostrando ou escondendo o campo usuário utilizando essa função do *JavaScript*:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function option_check(){
        if(document.getElementById("nivel_acesso").value != "0" && document.getElementById("nivel_acesso").value != ""){
            document.getElementById("hidden_div").style.display = "block";
        }
    }
```

E funciona na primeira vez, porém, se troco de "Administração" para "Sem Acesso", por exemplo, o campo continua lá. Como faço para verificar a cada vez que a opção for trocada?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Caso falso esconda novamente...

```
if(document.getElementById("nivel_acesso").value != "0" && document.getElementById("nivel_acesso").value != ""){
            document.getElementById("hidden_div").style.display = "block";
        }else{
     document.getElementById("hidden_div").style.display = "none";
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Basta inserir uma condição "else", para desativar o campo de texto caso ele já esteja sendo exibido...

```js
    function option_check(){
        if(document.getElementById("nivel_acesso").value != "0" && document.getElementById("nivel_acesso").value != ""){
            document.getElementById("hidden_div").style.display = "block";
        } else {
            document.getElementById("hidden_div").style.display = "none";
        }
    }
```

Uma dica: Caso queira trabalhar com interações real time, vc pode usar o AngularJS, um framework bem bacana de JS que vai te ajudar bastante nisso!

5 minutos desse tutorial já dá pra resolver seu problema e muitos outros: https://www.w3schools.com/angular/

Answer (score 0):

Amigo pra isso voce vai precisar utilizar PHP...faz o esquema de login e bota a condição pra que,se o usuario estiver logado,imprima na tela a parte que voce quer q ele veja...vai precisar de um banco de dados tb para salvar as informaçoes ou so faz uma função no javascript,salva os dados em uma variavel.a função para isso é a prompt();

Comment: Eu estou utilizando _PHP_ e a parte de _login_ está pronta, mas gostaria de quando alguém que estivesse logado fosse cadastrar um usuário, o campo "usuario" aparecesse e sumisse conforme a opção do _select_ "nivel_acesso" é trocada. Isso já está acontecendo, mas somente na primeira vez. Gostaria que acontecesse toda vez que a opção for trocada.